# using scrollbars with cytoscape.js

Tags: scrollbar, cytoscape.js

Has anyone used cytoscape.js with scrollbars?

cytoscapePanZoom works nicely, but scrollbars are useful also, and less confusing for some of us, some of the time.

Comment: What's the actual question, what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Sorry to have been unclear. How do I use scrollbars with cy.js?  Is there an example I can learn from?   Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you know the dimensions your canvas will have you can use `disablepanningEnabled: false`, then set the parent container's size manually and call [cy.resize()](http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.resize). There will be other details to work out, but I'll leave you at that, with the knowledge that you will need to do this manually as far as I can see from the official documentation.

Comment: Scrollbars aren't a good solution, for one, because they conflict with mouse zoom.  Graphs aren't static or linear, either, and that's where scrollbars are really useful.  For instance, a page has directionality, is linear, and is usually mostly static (or adds content in a linear direction).  A graph is none of those things.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sense of the viewport extent, you should use the navigator extension:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-navigator

It gives a bird's eye view of the graph so you can see how the extent of the viewport compares to the overall graph.

Edit: Also of note is this discussion in the tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/721